# Uninstall SQL Developer on Win 10

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, uninstallation

I might have installed the wrong version of Oracle SQL Developer (Version 4.1.4) on my Win 10 laptop. So I want to uninstall it and install a newer version.
Any idea what´s the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Delete the directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find the directory it was unzipped to, e.g. `C:\Program Files\sqldeveloper`, though it could be anywhere - quite likely in your downloads directory; and just delete that entire `sqldeveloper` directory.

There is no installation as such, it's just a Java application sitting in a directory.

Settings are held under your personal home directory, and when you unzip and run the later version (18.2 is current) you'll be asked if you want to migrate those settings, which will include any connections you've already defined.

[Read more in the 4.1 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55747_01/doc.41/e57986/installing-sql-developer.htm#RPTIG136).

Answer (score 4):

It is not installed so you can't uninstall it. To remove it from system do following:

- Delete base directory, where you unziped it (where you run it).
- Delete your user connection data - folder `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\SQL developer`
- If you don't have any other oracle software, delete your user configuration data - folder `C:\Users\<username>\Oracle`

Answer (score 0):

For me there are two directories:

```
C:\app\<username>\
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\
```